# CSV to JSON python - error in created JSON file

Tags: python, json, eof

I am pretty new to Python and trying to convert a csv file to a JSON file. 
(The CSV file is generated from [HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv))

So I am successfully creating a CSV file with this. This is for a college project so I am demonstrating that I can create a JSON file from a CSV and want to check the data structure is right before writing to MongoDB.

I use the below code snippet to do this:

```
    data = {}
    csv_file = open('Covid_19_Raw_Data.csv', 'r')
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    if os.path.exists("json_Raw_Data.json"):
        os.remove("json_Raw_Data.json")

    with open('json_Raw_Data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonFile: 
        for rows in csvReader: 
            json.dump(rows, jsonFile)
            jsonFile.write('\n')
    jsonFile.close()
```

The problem I have is when I try to validate the json, I get the below error:

> Error: Parse error on line 93: ...,   "4/10/20": "0"} {   "UID": "316",   "i
>   ---------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Any idea what I can do to fix this? Line 93 is the end of the first entry of many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While each row written is valid json, the whole contents is not. JSON data must be either array of valid JSON values, or dictionary/object containing those.

Easiest way to fix this is to start the file with single `[` and finish with `]`, then you have valid JSON.

Update: as `user3600952` correctly pointed out, rows should also be separated with commas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to mark it as the solution - only other thing I had to do was to add in a comma at the end of each line, and then not add one on the last line.        for rows in csvReader: 
            json.dump(rows, jsonFile)
            rowNumber+=1
            if(rowNumber != numberOfRows):
                jsonFile.write(',')
                jsonFile.write('\n')
        jsonFile.write(']')